# What is incorrect about this Microsoft sample for iOS APNS notification in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm a new Objective C programmer and [am following the directions here to set up push notification](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/get-started-notification-hubs-ios/#connecting-app).

When I add the following "optional" code I get an error, and am unable to compile:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:
                          [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@”alert”] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                          @"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

The error is "unexpected "@" in program", located here `userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"`.

What is the correct way to write this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the page, I could see that there's a minor mistake in the code:

In `[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@”alert”]` , where is `@”alert”` should be `@"alert"`

(**”** is a different character from **"**)

This should be enough to get rid of the error.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:
                          [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                          @"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```